# Availability of Legendary Actions

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, action-economy

Not sure I understand the timing/availability of Legendary Actions. Say Puff the Dragon has Legendary Actions A, B, and C, and is being attacked by a party consisting of W, X, Y, and Z. After W's turn, Puff uses Legendary Action A. Puff can't simultaneously use B and/or C; and now he only has two Legendary Actions left until his next turn begins. That much is clear.

Next X takes her turn, and afterwards, Puff wants to use another Legendary Action. Can he use Action A again? Or is Action A now unavailable until Puff refreshes his pool of Legendary Actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Legendary Action options are never restricted to once per round.

The general rules for legendary actions state:

> A legendary creature can take a certain number of special actions — called legendary actions — outside its turn. Only one legendary action option can be used at a time and only at the end of another creature’s turn. A legendary creature regains spent legendary actions at the start of its turn.

And the stat block description:

> The dragon can take 3 legendary actions, choosing from the options below. Only one legendary action option can be used at a time and only at the end of another creature’s turn. The dragon regains spent legendary actions at the start of its turn.

There are simply no rules which restrict an individual action to once per round, so it may be used as many times per round as the creature's remaining legendary actions allow.